# Backbone - Is it possible to bind a change event to a model, except for one property?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I would like a change event to fire anytime I change any property of the model, except for one. Is this possible? Besides doing:

```
model.bind('change:prop1', func);
model.bind('change:prop2', func);
model.bind('change:prop3', func);
etc....
```

Or alternatively, is there a way to find out which property triggered the change from within the event handler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `model.bind('change',function() {/*...*/})` and in the function use [`hasChanged`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-hasChanged) to check the attributes: `if(model.hasChanged('propIWantToExclude')) return;`

Comment: Can anyone answer the first part of the question? ie. How to fire a change event anytime I change any property of the model, except for one?

Comment: ^ just use the "change" like in the response... although i see it was edited, so you probably asked before the edit :)

Answer (score 4):

Justin's answer above will return when 'propIWantToExclude' and some other attributes are changed together. You probably don't want to do that, so you should also look at the size of `model.changedAttributes`:

```
if(model.changedAttributes.length == 1 && model.hasChanged('attrIWantToExclude')) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is should be: "model.hasChanged('attrIWantToExclude') && Object.keys(model.changedAttributes()).length == 1". Or "Object.keys(model.changed).length == 1 && ...". changedAttributes is a function and it returns a hash of changed objects or false if there are none. hash.length does not work so you need something like this: Object.keys(hash).length. false can be returned by changedAttributes and Object.keys(false) errors so you need a hasChanged test before the Object.keys reference on changedAttributes (or else reference internal model.changed). - http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes

Answer (score 1):

Responding to David Tuite's request to answer the first part of the question, you could set up a function to respond to the "changed" event and then trigger a custom event if the property that you want to ignore was not changed.

This logic would trigger the custom event: `'somePropertyOtherThanThePropIWantToExcludeChanged'` if the property was not changed. If multiple properties were changed, including the one you want to ignore, then the custom event would also NOT fire:

```
model.bind('change', function(){
    if( !model.hasChanged('propIWantToExclude') ){
        model.trigger('somePropertyOtherThanThePropIWantToExcludeChanged');
    }
});
```

Comment: Who's `David Tuite`? What's "first part of the question"?